# WS transport error: i/o error: Broken pipe (os error 32); terminate connection

Tags: extrinsic, substrate-node

I am submitting an unsigned extrinsic using `subxt` crate in rust.

I have a simple u64 number inside `StorageValue` called `Nonce` which keeps track of number of transactions submitted (needed for generating the transaction tag in `validate_unsigned` method). And I implemented `ValidateUnsigned` trait inside the pallet as shown below.

```rust
// Inherent call is not validated as unsigned
        fn validate_unsigned(_source: TransactionSource, call: &Self::Call) -> TransactionValidity {
            match call {
                Call::allowed_unsigned { .. } => Ok(Default::default()),
                Call::transfer { .. } => {
                    log::info!("***************** validate_unsigned for transfer is called and nonce: {} **************", Nonce::<T>::get());
                    let nonce = Nonce::<T>::get();
                    let priority = u64::max_value() - nonce;
                    let mut valid_transaction_builder =
                        ValidTransaction::with_tag_prefix("example")
                            .priority(priority)
                            // .and_provides((nonce,))
                            // .and_requires((nonce - 1,))
                            .propagate(true);
                    valid_transaction_builder = valid_transaction_builder.and_provides((nonce,));
                    if nonce > 0 {
                        valid_transaction_builder =
                            valid_transaction_builder.and_requires((nonce - 1,));
                    }
                    let validity = valid_transaction_builder.build();
                    log::info!("***************** validate_unsigned for transfer exited successfully **************");
                    // Nonce::<T>::mutate(|n| *n += 1);
                    validity
                }
                _ => UnknownTransaction::NoUnsignedValidator.into(),
            }
        }
```

```bash
2023-12-08 15:45:45.150  INFO tokio-runtime-worker ar_pallet_transactions::pallet: ***************** validate_unsigned for transfer is called and nonce: 0 **************    
2023-12-08 15:45:45.150  INFO tokio-runtime-worker ar_pallet_transactions::pallet: ***************** validate_unsigned for transfer exited successfully **************    
2023-12-08 15:45:45.151 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_core::tracing: send="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"result\":\"muUjDyalEplJwoJV\",\"id\":4}"
2023-12-08 15:45:45.151 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_core::tracing: send="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"author_extrinsicUpdate\",\"params\":{\"subscription\":\"muUjDyalEplJwoJV\",\"result\":\"ready\"}}"
2023-12-08 15:45:45.151 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_core::tracing: send="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"result\":\"muUjDyalEplJwoJV\",\"id\":4}"
2023-12-08 15:45:45.151 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_core::tracing: send="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"author_extrinsicUpdate\",\"params\":{\"subscription\":\"muUjDyalEplJwoJV\",\"result\":{\"broadcast\":[\"12D3KooWRVfrZqHwC3CV6VAgDDLWx6oZDbkRqUfJKrVQ4BJdPWzf\"]}}}"
2023-12-08 15:45:45.154 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_core::tracing: recv="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":5,\"method\":\"author_unwatchExtrinsic\",\"params\":[\"muUjDyalEplJwoJV\"]}"
2023-12-08 15:45:45.154 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_core::tracing: send="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"result\":true,\"id\":5}"
2023-12-08 15:45:45.154 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_core::tracing: send="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"result\":true,\"id\":5}"
2023-12-08 15:45:45.154 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_server::transport::ws: WS transport error: i/o error: Broken pipe (os error 32); terminate connection: 2
2023-12-08 15:45:45.154 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_server::transport::ws: WS transport error: send failed: Networking or low-level protocol error: connection closed
```

I can see from the logs that `validate_unsigned` is being called and exiting successfully. But after that I see `WS transport error: i/o error: Broken pipe (os error 32); terminate connection:` and then the subsequent calls to submit extrinsic from subxt are timing out. I assumed that it has to do with the websocket error we are seeing before.

And more over I can see the extrinsic (the first) inside the pallet being executed successfully.

When I try to submit the second extrinsic I can see that `validate_unsigned` is once again successful,

```bash
2023-12-08 15:45:55.524  INFO tokio-runtime-worker ar_pallet_transactions::pallet: ***************** validate_unsigned for transfer is called and nonce: 1 **************    
2023-12-08 15:45:55.524  INFO tokio-runtime-worker ar_pallet_transactions::pallet: ***************** validate_unsigned for transfer exited successfully **************
```

but I don't see the extrinsic inside the pallet being called. And the caller (subxt) of this extrinsic is timing out.

Please feel free to ask any questions or clarifications